# solving problems for lists in python

Tags: python

How to write a code which takes two lists as input and returns multiplication for the lists

e.g Result should look like this.

```
First-list [1,2]
Second-list [2,1]
Your result [2,1,4,2]
```

I have tried with the code

```
list1=[1,2]
list2=[2,1]
list3=list1*list2
```

Comment: Please see "How do I ask and answer homework questions?" - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: There are lots of possible definitions that `[1,2] * [2,1]` *could* have (though Python implements none of them, precisely *because* there's no clear reason for one of them to be *the* way to multiply lists).

Comment: @Sayse; that's not a duplicate; it deals with element-wise product; OP needs full cross.

Comment: Hint: look up "list comprehensions" in Python

Comment: I’ll second what @kaya3 has said. It doesn’t look like you’ve made as much as the slightest effort to solve this... Your example isn’t even matrix multiplication. Working code for you to copy-paste isn’t a substitute for the amount of work you need to put in in order to actually understand what you’re doing.

Answer (score 0):

First-list =[1,2]
Second-list=[2,1]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't find a duplicate (I'll delete if anyone does)

You can use a list comprehension

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [2, 1]
>>> [x * y for x in a for y in b]
[2, 1, 4, 2]
```